# Using php and mysql how to create a function to insert data in database

Tags: php, mysql

i have to trying to creating a function to insert data in DB.

```
public function insert_db($db,$table,$data){

                foreach ($data as $column => $value)
                {
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} ({$column}) VALUES (:{$column});";
                    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->execute(array(':'.$column => $value));
                }
            }
```

I found this function here. But its not working, its say

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in ...
```

I'm using "new mysqli" , how can i solve this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `$db->prepare($sql)` can also return `FALSE` if there is any error, in such cases you will receive below error

`Call to a member function execute() on boolean`

> `mysqli_prepare()` returns a statement object or FALSE if an error
>   occurred.

Read more here : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php